# Vue js renderizar video

Tags: html5, vue.js

Tenho o seguinte componente:

```
<div v-for="video in videos" :key="video.title">
    <video class="video-js" controls preload="auto">
        <source v-bind:src="video.src" type="video/mp4">
    </video>
</div>
```

script:

```
<script>
export default {
data: () => ({
    videos: [
      { title: "v1", src: "../../assets/videos/v1.mp4", desc: "v1"},
      { title: "v2", src: "../../assets/videos/v2.mp4", desc: "v2"}
    ]
  })
}
</script>
```

Porém o `vue.js` não está "convertendo" o caminho do video.

Ao usar `<source src="../../assets/videos/v1.mp4" type="video/mp4">`
no meu html fica assim: `<source src="/static/media/v1.dc6c1ef.mp4" type="video/mp4">`.

Como posso ter um `array` de links e fazer o `bind` com o `vue.js` corretamente?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tente assim:

```
import v1 from "../../assets/videos/v1.mp4";
import v2 from "../../assets/videos/v2.mp4";

export default {
data: () => ({
    videos: [
      { title: "v1", src: v1, desc: "v1"},
      { title: "v2", src: v2, desc: "v2"}
    ]
  })
}
```

Comment: Perfeito!! funcionou.. teria com importar vários videos usando um `import` só?

Comment: Não sei, acho que não. Em um loop, acho que você pode usar requires. Até o import talvez funcione em loop, nunca tentei.